# Uno Material Card Formatting

Tags: uno-platform

I am using the Uno Material Card in my app.  Recently there was a change to Uno.Material in the way it was initialized. I implemented that- with some help from @sbilogan in this response: [Uno Material Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907112/uno-platform-initialize-material).  However- the text in my cards no longer have the formatting.  I tried adding back in the template to format the text- but it did not work.  I am guessing something is being changed here- but not sure how to proceed.  Here is my sample code and screenshots:

```
<material:Card x:Name="appInfoCard" HeaderContent="App Information"
               SubHeaderContent="Tap to see more"
               SupportingContent="App: "            
               Style="{ThemeResource MaterialOutlinedCardStyle}"
               MediaContent="Example"        
               Foreground="{ThemeResource SubPageTextColor}"
               Background="{ThemeResource cardBackground}">
            <material:Card.MediaContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Padding="10">
                            <Omitted for clarity>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </material:Card.MediaContentTemplate>
            </material:Card>
```

The code with the full template(I had to use this at one point- but the a change was merged into Uno Material so I did not have to use it anymore)

```
<material:Card.HeaderContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                    Margin="16,14,16,0"
                    Style="{ThemeResource MaterialHeadline6}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </material:Card.HeaderContentTemplate>
   <material:Card.SubHeaderContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                    Margin="16,0,16,14"
                    Style="{ThemeResource MaterialBody2}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </material:Card.SubHeaderContentTemplate>
```

The top image was made with Uno Material build 774.  The bottom was with 782.
[image: Image- before and after]

Comment: I added an issue in github- hopefully in the right place.  If it is incorrect- please let me know.  Here is the issue: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/6310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in my MaterialColorOverridePallette.xaml- I had the following set:
Green
Green

For some reason- it did not interfere with the formatting before 774.  After 774- it removes the formatting from these categories for some reason.  Removing them caused them to work as expected in 802 and beyond.  Hopefully this helps someone else.